# How to include custom post type title in BuddyPress activity feed

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

I am using custom post types that I will be displaying within my BuddyPress activity feed. I am able to setup the post types to work within the feed just fine, but I am unable to find documentation about how to display the title within the feed. Here is my code, I want to display the post title where `[title]` is:

```
add_post_type_support( 'news', 'buddypress-activity' );

function customize_page_tracking_args() {
    // Check if the Activity component is active before using it.
    if ( ! bp_is_active( 'activity' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    bp_activity_set_post_type_tracking_args( 'news', array(
        'component_id'             => buddypress()->blogs->id,
        'action_id'                => 'new_news_item',
        'bp_activity_admin_filter' => __( 'News', 'custom-domain' ),
        'bp_activity_front_filter' => __( 'Pages', 'custom-domain' ),
        'contexts'                 => array( 'activity', 'member' ),
        'activity_comment'         => true,
        'bp_activity_new_post'     => __( '%1$s - <a href="%2$s">News: [title]</a>', 'custom-textdomain' ),
        'bp_activity_new_post_ms'  => __( '%1$s - <a href="%2$s">News: [title]</a>, on the site %3$s', 'custom-textdomain' ),
        'position'                 => 100,
    ) );
}
add_action( 'bp_init', 'customize_page_tracking_args' );
```

Within this line of code I can see that `%1$s` is the user name and `%2$s` is the post link. Are there more of these snippets within BuddyPress that I can use, specifically one for the post title?

```
'bp_activity_new_post'     => __( '%1$s - <a href="%2$s">News: [title]</a>', 'custom-textdomain' ),
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can read this Codex page on BuddyPress.org site. It has more information, and describes how to tighten the connection between CPT and BuddyPress activity feed. [Here](https://codex.buddypress.org/plugindev/post-types-activities/#customizing-post-type-activity-content) is the example.

Comment: Unfortunately this still does not answer my question. I need to know specifically how to add the `post title` when defining `bp_activity_new_post`. The BuddyPress documentation covers the user name `%1$s` and the post link `%2$s` but not the title.